# Facebook connect with Android webview

Tags: facebook, android-webview

So here’s the thing :
I’m building an Androïd webview app from a responsive website.
When I tried to connect myself with Facebook connect on the App, it connects myself on the browser instead of the app...
Does anyone has a clue to solve my problem ?
Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

Just do one thing and try if it works.

```
yourWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
{

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return false;
            }


            @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            public boolean 
            shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, 
            WebResourceRequest request) {

                return false;
            }


});
```